# /j_spring_security_check HTTP error 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-java-config

It looks like some filter not added.
I use Spring security 3.2.0.RELEASE with java-config. 
Full project posted on [GitHub](https://github.com/intrade/inventory) 
SecurityConfig.java is here: [SecurityConfig.java](https://github.com/intrade/inventory/blob/master/src/main/java/com/springapp/mvc/InitApp/SecurityConfig.java)

I try to set up filter in:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/app/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/app/")
                .failureUrl("/?error=1")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout");
    }
```

After csrf().disable() - But problem not solved...
Help me please to solve this problem for I can use /j_spring_security_check with my own CustomUserDetailsService!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no experience with Spring Security Java Config, but I checked your code and the API and it seems that setting login processing URL will let you login:

```
AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
```

So your code should be:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/app/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .loginPage("/")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/app/")
            .failureUrl("/?error=1")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout");
}
```

I would expect this is set by default.

In addition, to make use of MyCustomUserDetailsService, instead of autowiring it as it is now (Proxy created by Spring), I would configure it manually:

```
public class MyCustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public MyCustomUserDetailsService(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }
    // ...    
}
```

Notice, no @Service/@Component annotations and DAO injected via Ctor. In security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .and()
                .userDetailsService(new MyCustomUserDetailsService(userDAO));
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now I am sure, the UserDetailService is properly configured. And for sure it will be used while logging in in the application.

I also noticed that the username and password is not used. This is because in login.jsp you use j_username and j_password whereas username parameter should be username and password parameter should be password.

```
<input type="text" id="username" class="span4" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
<input type="password" id="password" class="span4" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

Look at the FormLoginConfigurer class.

Comment: Ok, but now looks like my MyCustomUserDetailsService is not in use, but is using Spring UserDetailsService.

In method loadUserByUsername Y insert this line: System.out.println(login); but nothing not printed to shell. And no one exception...

Comment: To make use of your service MyCustomUserDetailsService I would not autowire it but instead I would create it manually in SecurityConfig (anyways it is used only for security configuration). I will edit the original answer to visualize this.

Comment: Thank you! Can I contact you if I have new questions?
I forget one week to resolve Spring security problems.